# What is this plant growing in utah, usa

Tags: identification

Do you know what plant this is? Grown in utah, usa

[image]

Comment: Can't get to it in your Google Drive. Can you upload the picture here?

Comment: Sorry about that. I can't upload it here because the image is too big. Let me get that permission changed

Comment: Can you see it now?

Comment: hate to say it but that picture does not show how or where the plant grows.  Can you add some details?

Comment: You have to resize it in paint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My instinct was Plantain, a rather cool weed.

[image: Narrow Leaf Plantain]

Comment: How did you post the picture instead of a link? My pictures seem to be too big

Comment: I am the last person to ask I think!  I simply right click and click save picture location.  Then I use the other site's tool bar for adding a link.  Not a picture.  You can try.  It is different with every other site, why I don't know!  Keep kicking around and you get more reliable.  Ugh.  My hubby is a major engineer for a major company and I thought HE would be our IT GUY!  Oh well.  Try just clicking picture location and posting it as a link.

Comment: Your picture was clear as day, Will...these computers aren't that user friendly...!